# Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, web-services

i am making an application using Silverlight. In that application on button click i am calling a web service method(Web Service is deployed on IIS). i am getting error as

```
Message:AuthenticateUser_CheckUserAuthorizationCompleted : [Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.00&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred
   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at Console1.AuthenticateUser.CheckUserAuthorizationCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at Console1.LogIn.AuthenticateUser_CheckUserAuthorizationCompleted(Object sender, CheckUserAuthorizationCompletedEventArgs e)
```

Where `AuthenticateUser_CheckUserAuthorizationCompleted` is the event from which i am calling the web method. I also checked the error in Fiddler tool and it shows
 `ErrorCode: 10060.A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.130:80`. I am not getting what is the issue. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note, the following portion of the error:

> Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.00&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred

In order to keep the Silverlight runtime slim, a lot of strings were omitted in favour of links to them online. If you follow the link, it will tell you more about the error that you encountered.

> An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerException for exception details.

In order to resolve this issue, we need to see what the `InnerException` looks like.